# What's a compact way to express the product of terms in arithmetic progression?

Tags: factorial, closed-form, products, arithmetic-progressions

There is a notation for the product of the first $n$ positive integers. My question is whether it is possible to express the product of any other non-trivial arithmetic progression with $n$ terms compactly.

That is, given the sequence $$a,a+d,a+2d,a+3d,\cdots, a+(n-1)d,$$ where $ad\ne 0,$ is there a simple closed form expression equal to $$\prod_{i=1}^n {a+(i-1)d},$$ possibly not using anything more than the elementary operations, and of course the factorial?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Product shows how to do it with gamma functions.  I would suspect there isn't anything much nicer.

Comment: You could also use [Pochhammer functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials), aka falling or rising factorials.